# check if dictionary key has empty value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
dict1 ={"city":"","name":"yass","region":"","zipcode":"",
       "phone":"","address":"","tehsil":"", "planet":"mars"}
```

I am trying to create a new dictionary that will be based on dict1 but,

1. it will not contain keys with empty strings.
2. it will not contain those keys that I dont want to include.

i have been able to fulfill the requirement 2 but getting problem with requirement 1. Here is what my code looks like.

```
dict1 ={"city":"","name":"yass","region":"","zipcode":"",
   "phone":"","address":"","tehsil":"", "planet":"mars"}

blacklist = set(("planet","tehsil"))    
new = {k:dict1[k] for k in dict1 if k not in blacklist}
```

this gives me the dictionary without the keys: "tehsil", "planet"
I have also tried the following but it didnt worked.

```
new = {k:dict1[k] for k in dict1 if k not in blacklist and dict1[k] is not None}
```

the resulting dict should look like the one below:

```
new = {"name":"yass"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would have to be the fastest way to do it (using set [difference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)):

```
>>> dict1 = {"city":"","name":"yass","region":"","zipcode":"",
       "phone":"","address":"","tehsil":"", "planet":"mars"}
>>> blacklist = {"planet","tehsil"}
>>> {k: dict1[k] for k in dict1.viewkeys() - blacklist if dict1[k]}
{'name': 'yass'}
```

White list version (using set [intersection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)):

```
>>> whitelist = {'city', 'name', 'region', 'zipcode', 'phone', 'address'}
>>> {k: dict1[k] for k in dict1.viewkeys() & whitelist if dict1[k]}
{'name': 'yass'}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. what will be the solution if I only want  non empty white list values?

Comment: @yasra002 added that as well

Comment: Which option is better using sets that I used or the one one that you used. I am pretty new to python so I am not sure which one is the best one.

Comment: @yasra002 People only wrote sets like `set((1, 2, 3))` back in Python <= 2.6 when there **was no** set literal(`{1, 2, 3}`). What you are doing is creating a `tuple` and passing it to a `set` constructor. Nowadays we have set literals so you should use them ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is a white list version:

```
>>> dict1 ={"city":"","name":"yass","region":"","zipcode":"",
       "phone":"","address":"","tehsil":"", "planet":"mars"}
>>> whitelist = ["city","name","planet"]
>>> dict2 = dict( (k,v) for k, v in dict1.items() if v and k in whitelist )
>>> dict2
{'planet': 'mars', 'name': 'yass'}
```

Blacklist version:

```
>>> blacklist = set(("planet","tehsil"))
>>> dict2 = dict( (k,v) for k, v in dict1.items() if v and k not in blacklist )
>>> dict2
{'name': 'yass'}
```

Both are essentially the same expect one has `not in` the other `in`. If you version of python supports it you can do:

```
>>> dict2 = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if v and k in whitelist}
```

and

```
>>> dict2 = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if v and k not in blacklist}
```

Comment: may as well use a dictionary comprehension `{k: v for k, v ....}`, even though it's not Python 2.6 compatible like this, we know OP is using 2.7+

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  Consider:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2012, 00:00:54) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120414 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dict1 ={"city":"","name":"yass","region":"","zipcode":"",
...    "phone":"","address":"","tehsil":"", "planet":"mars"}
>>> 
>>> def isgood(undesired, key, val): return key not in undesired and key and val
... 
>>> dict([x for x in dict1.items() if isgood(["planet", "tehsil"], *x)])
{'name': 'yass'}
```

Comment: @lshpeck but this will only work for the fixed length dictionary? Correct me if Iam wrong?

Comment: No, this will work for any length dictionary. (true both before and after my edit)

Answer (score 1):

Simply test `dict1[k]` for Truth value (instead of `is None`.).

```
new = {k:dict1[k] for k in dict1 if k not in blacklist and dict1[k]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing if the value is not an empty string is not done using `is not None`.

An empty string evaluates as False, while any non-empty string evaluates as True. Hence, you can test it directly, and simply remove the `is not None` from your expression :

```
new = {k:dict1[k] for k in dict1 if k not in blacklist and dict1[k]}
```

Answer (score 0):

dict2 = { (k,v) for k,v in dict1.items() if ( k in whitelist ) and ( v != "" ) }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).