# Is there a difference between 'and' and '&' with respect to python sets?

Tags: python, set

I got very good help for question [check if dictionary key has empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693779/check-if-dictionary-key-has-empty-value) . But I was wondering if there is a difference between `and` and `&` in python? I assume that they should be similar?

```
dict1 ={"city":"","name":"yass","region":"","zipcode":"",
   "phone":"","address":"","tehsil":"", "planet":"mars"}

whitelist = {"name", "phone", "zipcode", "region", "city",
             "munic", "address", "subarea"}

result = {k: dict1[k] for k in dict1.viewkeys() & whitelist if dict1[k]}
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, the question is also referring to set operations

Comment: @jamylak The set part of the question was added as an edit after I voted close.

Comment: Yes. I am writing about that. was getting keyerror when I user "and" instead of '&'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`and` is a logical operator which is used to compare two values, IE:

```
> 2 > 1 and 2 > 3
True
```

`&` is a bitwise operator that is used to perform a bitwise AND operation:

```
> 255 & 1
1
```

**Update**

With respect to [set operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), the `&` operator is equivalent to the `intersection()` operation, and creates a new set with elements common to s and t:

```
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = set([3, 4, 5])
>>> a & b
set([3])
```

`and` is still just a logical comparison function, and will treat a `set` argument as a non-false value. It will also return the last value if neither of the arguments is `False`:

```
>>> a and b
set([3, 4, 5])
>>> a and b and True
True
>>> False and a and b and True
False
```

---

For what its worth, note also that according to the python docs for [Dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), the object returned by `dict1.viewkeys()` is a view object that is "set-like":

> The objects returned by `dict.viewkeys()`, `dict.viewvalues()` and `dict.viewitems()` are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes.
>
> ...
>
> **`dictview & other`**
>
> Return the intersection of the dictview and the other object as a new set.
>
> ...

Comment: you should use `set` not `Set`

Comment: Good catch, thanks. From the docs: `The built-in set and frozenset types were designed based on lessons learned from the sets module.`

Comment: & isn't **completely** bitwise.  For example, you can't use it to compare floats, or a float with a NaN.

Answer (score 7):

- `and` is logical and
- `&` is bitwise and

logical `and` returns the second value if both values evaluate to true.

For sets `&` is intersection.

If you do:

```
In [25]: a = {1, 2, 3}

In [26]: b = {3, 4, 5}

In [27]: a and b
Out[27]: set([3, 4, 5])

In [28]: a & b
Out[28]: set([3])
```

This be because `bool(a) == True` and `bool(b) == True` so `and` returns the second set.  `&` returns the intersection of the sets.

[(`set` doc)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Answer (score 3):

Yes `and` is a logical and whereas `&` is a bitwise and. See example -

```
>>> 1 and 2
2
>>> 1 & 2
0
```

The first result is due to short circuiting. Python tests 1 and finds it true and returns the 2. But, the second part does 01 (Binary 1) & 10 (Binary 2) hence evaluating to 00 (1 & 0, 0 &1) , which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

`&`is the bit-wise and operator, `and` is the boolean logic operator. They're quite different, don't confuse them! For example:

```
7 & 3
=> 3

True and False
=> False
```

Comment: Note: this answer was posted _before_ OP modified the question, indicating that the operators were to be applied on sets

Answer (score 1):

````
>>> help('&')

+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Operator                                        | Description                           |
+=================================================+=======================================+
| ``lambda``                                      | Lambda expression                     |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``if`` -- ``else``                              | Conditional expression                |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``or``                                          | Boolean OR                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``and``                                         | Boolean AND                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``not`` ``x``                                   | Boolean NOT                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``in``, ``not in``, ``is``, ``is not``, ``<``,  | Comparisons, including membership     |
| ``<=``, ``>``, ``>=``, ``<>``, ``!=``, ``==``   | tests and identity tests,             |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``|``                                           | Bitwise OR                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``^``                                           | Bitwise XOR                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``&``                                           | Bitwise AND                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``<<``, ``>>``                                  | Shifts                                |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``+``, ``-``                                    | Addition and subtraction              |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``*``, ``/``, ``//``, ``%``                     | Multiplication, division, remainder   |
|                                                 | [8]                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``+x``, ``-x``, ``~x``                          | Positive, negative, bitwise NOT       |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``**``                                          | Exponentiation [9]                    |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``x[index]``, ``x[index:index]``,               | Subscription, slicing, call,          |
| ``x(arguments...)``, ``x.attribute``            | attribute reference                   |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| ``(expressions...)``, ``[expressions...]``,     | Binding or tuple display, list        |
| ``{key: value...}``, ```expressions...```       | display, dictionary display, string   |
|                                                 | conversion                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
````